# Is there any way to export custom google compute images using Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I want to export custom compute image and store in bucket. I can use `gcloud` command but I am looking for Terraform solution.

This is working fine. But it is pain to logged in in `gcloud` cli.

```
resource "null_resource" "export_image" {
    triggers = {
      image_name = "something-export"
    }

   provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "gcloud compute images export --destination-uri gs://test-bucket/my-exported-image.vmdk --image ${self.triggers.image_name} --compute-service-account test@test.com"
      environment = {
        CLOUDSDK_AUTH_CREDENTIAL_FILE_OVERRIDE = "service-account.json"
      }
    }
 }
```

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Terraform deploys resource, not perform operation on the resources. AFAIK, you can't.

Comment: Is there any reasons because what i am trying to do is just export an image and keep it in bucket. (just want a clarification)